# My PIR sensor watch() not invoke

Tags: gpio, node.js

I installed nodejs on my raspberry pi 3 model B v2. Then I connected PIR sensor using onoff (gpio module for nodejs) module.

The problem is when I connect the power cable to the sensor if block triggered and after disconnected power cable else block triggered.

What I want is when the object moves in front of the sensor, I need to get the if block triggered.

```
var gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
var pir = new gpio(12, 'in', 'both');
 pir.watch(function(err, value) {
if (value == 1) {
    console.log('Intruder alert');
} else {
     console.log('Intruder gone');
}});
```

Comment: Please provide link to your sensor datasheet. Also update your code to check and print out error if error is not null.

Comment: A photo of the connections would also be useful.

Comment: Did you come up with an answer to this? I'm experiencing the exact same problem and it's doing my nut. Using `cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value` reveals the hardware works and it's a software issue.

Comment: I found the solution for that but didn't remember the exact solution because it's quite old. if you have a GitHub account please share your username. then I can share my repo it's not public repo.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just created a new GitHub account, username GaryOtt.

Comment: I sent invite for repo.hope you will find a solution

Comment: I see you worked around the problem by polling `pir.readSync()` using `setInterval()`. Unfortunately, I need a really fast polling, best done outside the JavaScript event loop (like the Gpio.watch method should) but thank you for going out of your way to help a random internet stranger.

Comment: in that case, nodejs has worker thread try to leverage that. that might be solve your issue.